# Proper way to call a c-function taking non-const pointer arguments, const_cast, reinterpret_cast, launder

Tags: c, c++17, reinterpret-cast, const-cast

What is proper way to call a c-function taking non-const custom pointer arguments from c++?

Take, as a very common example, the function `fftw_plan_dft_1d` from FFTW3. http://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-DFTs.html#Complex-DFTs

```
fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_1d(int n0,
                           fftw_complex *in, fftw_complex *out,
                           int sign, unsigned flags);
```

(`fftw_complex` is a typedef for `double[2]`).

Suppose I want apply this function to a couple of const-correct c++ containers.

```
std::vector<std::complex<double>> const In = {...};
std::vector<std::complex<double>> Out(In.size());
```

**How should I do that?**

_ First iteration, I have to extract the data pointer from the container,

```
assert(In.size() == Out.size());
fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_1d(In.size(),
                           In.data(), Out.data(), // error const
                           FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

_ Second iteration

but since it is const I have to constcast. 
<s>I assume that this is the only possible solution assuming that the reason for the C-interfact is that C doesn't have const arguments.</s>

```
fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(In.size(),
                           const_cast<std::complex<double>*>(In.data()), // error std::complex is not convertible to fftw_complex
                           Out.data(), 
                           FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

_ Third iteration

Now, I have to convert `std::complex<double>` to `fftw_complex` (`double[2]`). Fortunately `std::complex<double>` is required to have the same layout as `double[2]`.

```
fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(In.size(),
                           reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(const_cast<std::complex<double>*>(In.data())), // is this UB?
                           reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(Out.data()), 
                           FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

and now I am paranoid, apparently `reinterpret_cast` is always UB. 
I don't know how to use `std::launder` but I know that it can save `reinterpret_cast` UB in certain situations.

```
fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(In.size(),
                           std::launder(reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(const_cast<std::complex<double>*>(In.data()))), // needs c++17
                           std::launder(reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(Out.data())), 
                           FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

**At the end of the day, is this a reasonable way to call a C-function that involves const and reinterpretation of types?**

**Am I too paranoid? or is it just that calling C from C++ is always formally UB in cases like these and I can't do anything about it?**

Comment: C [*does* have `const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/const) (since C89/C90) but some poorly written libraries do not use it in their function prototypes.

Comment: @TypeIA, I noticed that, what should one do in those cases? break const correctness from the beginning or use `const_cast`. To be clear in this case, the only reason I know that I can pass a const pointer to this library is because of the last parameter `FFTW_ESTIMATE` which promises not overwrite the data of first pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're indeed being quite paranoid, and I also think that's a good thing. Keep it up. A little paranoia will greatly reduce the number of times you shoot yourself in the foot!

You correctly identified the need to cast away the `const` qualifier because the library doesn't use `const` in its function signature. And you correctly identified the solution using `const_cast<>`.

You also correctly identified that `reinterpret_cast<>` is *technically* UB in this situation ***if*** you don't assume that `fftw_complex` is typedefed as `double[2]`. (I'm not familiar with FFTW3, so I don't know if that is even true or not, but you probably do.) If you know it's a typedef, it is not UB because the types are the same, just aliased under different names. If you don't know, it's *"probably"* still safe, but yes, I think that might be a case where you have to make a little leap of faith, knowing that any sane, real world compiler should do the right thing. There's a [note to this effect](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-numbers.html) in the FFTW3 documentation.

> C++ has its own complex template class, defined in the standard  header file. Reportedly, the C++ standards committee has recently agreed to mandate that the storage format used for this type be binary-compatible with the C99 type, i.e. an array T[2] with consecutive real [0] and imaginary [1] parts. (See report http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2002/n1388.pdf WG21/N1388.) Although not part of the official standard as of this writing, the proposal stated that: “This solution has been tested with all current major implementations of the standard library and shown to be working.” To the extent that this is true, if you have a variable complex *x, you can pass it directly to FFTW via reinterpret_cast(x).

(Of course [this layout guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) **is** now part of the standard as of C++11.)

Finally, a note about C++ style casts. Everyone says you *should* use them instead of C casts, and this is true in most situations, but C-style casts **are** well-defined and the program isn't going to blow up if you use them. The tradeoff is one of conciseness and readable code (C-style) against explicit declaration of intent (C++-style). The exact rules for what the C++ compiler does with C-style casts [are defined here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). In my personal opinion, since you're already dealing with a C library with less-than-perfect function signatures, it is not the end of the world to simply C-style cast to a `(double *)` and call it a day.

Comment: `fftw_complex` is a typedef of `double[2]` the problem is that I am reinterpreting from `std::complex<double>&` to `double[2]&`. `std::complex` is indeed now mandated to have `double[2]` layout, what I don't know if that saves `reinterpret_cast` from being UB, cppreference seems to say that reinterpret is ok here (at least for refences, doesn't say anything about pointers) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex.

Comment: I am tempted from you answer to say that all the paranoia of `std::launder(reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(const_cast<std::complex<double>*>(in)))` can be simply replaced by `(fftw_complex*)in`, because I am using C-library anyway. Good. (BTW there is no cast to `(double*)` involved I think.)

Comment: It means `reinterpret_cast` isn't needed at all, because given `p = &c[0]`, `p` and `p + 1` are guaranteed to be addresses of valid `double`s and that's all you need (minus casting away the `const`). I agree that `std::launder()` seems like overkill and personally I would probably write `const_cast<double *>(&c[0][0])` but I see nothing wrong with the C-style cast version.

Comment: Also maybe worth observing that the layout guarantees of `std::vector` come into play here too, such that given `std::vector<std::complex> v`, you can safely assume that the double components of each complex value are all packed at consecutive memory addresses.

Comment: Thanks, you say that `reinterpret_cast` is not needed at all, but how would you call `fftw_plan_dft_1d` on `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` without using `reinterpret_cast` or c-style cast? I don't see how.

Comment: I thought `std::complex<T>` had an `operator[]` that returned a `T&` but it does not, so you are correct and a `reinterpret_cast<>` is needed.

Comment: `launder` is implicit when you cross an ABI defined call, that is when you call a separately compiled code